# Prevent Visual Studio 2010 Setup Project adding files to source control

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, setup-project

We have a solution with few C# projects and one setup project. The whole solution is bound to TFS source control (and whole folder structure is mapped to source control).

All projects have the same output folder - parent folder is mapped to source control but output folder is not added to source control.

Setup project is set to add specific assemblies from output folder to GAC (File System Editor -> Add -> Assembly -> Browse). **Visual Studio automatically adds those assemblies to source control. And since those assemblies are our projects, we don't want them in source control because they are regenerated on each build.**

We don't want to use Primary Output because:

- Setup adds a lot of dependencies
- Excluding them is easy, but each time we change references or something, setup project gets refreshed, finds new dependencies or something like that
- **we want to be in control what files will be dsitributed with our setup** without setup project interference

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like bad practices all over the place.

First, your company has TFS, Visual Studio 2010 and yet -- still using the [soon-to-be-obsolete](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs.aspx) Visual Studio Deployment project. Like it or not, sooner or later you'll be migrating to WiX.

And if you or your stakeholders still insist on vdproj, why reference **your own assemblies** from GAC? Primary Output is far from being perfect but it beats GAC'ing on your development machine. 
GAC on runtime, not design time ©

Finally, even if for some reason you still want to reference your own binaries, do it from a common lib folder kept in the source control instead of the GAC.

Comment: We had just migrated to VS2010 (while on VS2008 everything was ok). I was not aware of soon-to-be-obsolete deployment project, thanks. Our assemblies has to go to GAC because they are used by our custom SQL Server SSIS components and as such they have to be in GAC. Project Output is not an option because it finds too many unwanted dependencies and keeps excluding=false for some of them. ClickOnce is not an option because it can't store assemblies in GAC. I will take a look at WiX. Voted up for useful informations.

Comment: Marked your post as answer because it is not possible to achieve what I tried to achieve and you have a good point about bad practices.

Comment: ["Far better an approximate answer to the right question, which is often vague, than an exact answer to the wrong question, which can always be made precise."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Tukey#Quotes) -- John Tukey